# How to tell if sidekiq is connected to redis server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

Using the console, how can I tell if sidekiq is connected to a redis server?  I want to be able to do something like this:

```
if (sidekiq is connected to redis) # psuedo code
  MrWorker.perform_async('do_work', user.id)
else
  MrWorker.new.perform('do_work', user.id)
end
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use Redis info provided by Sidekiq:

```
redis_info = Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.info }
redis_info['connected_clients'] # => "16"
```

Took it from [Sidekiq's Sinatra status app](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/web.rb).

Comment: If there's no redis connection or server available that `conn.info` would raise an exception `Redis::CannotConnectError`

Answer (score 15):

I make this method to Rails whit the obove answer, return `true` if connected and `false` if not.

```
  def redis_connected?
    !!Sidekiq.redis(&:info) rescue false
  end
```

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want to know if there is a Sidekiq process up and running to process jobs at a given point in time.  With Sidekiq 3.0, you can do this:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

ps = Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new
if ps.size > 0
  MyWorker.perform_async(1,2,3)
else
  MyWorker.new.perform(1,2,3)
end
```

Sidekiq::ProcessSet gives you almost real-time (updated every 5 sec) info about any running Sidekiq processes.

Answer (score 3):

jumping off @overallduka's answer, for those using the [okcomputer](https://github.com/sportngin/okcomputer) gem, this is the custom check i set up:

```
class SidekiqCheck < OkComputer::Check
  def check
    if sidekiq_accessible?
      mark_message "ok"
    else
      mark_failure
    end
  end

  private
  def sidekiq_accessible?
    begin
      Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.info }
    rescue Redis::CannotConnectError
    end.present?
  end
end

OkComputer::Registry.register "sidekiq", SidekiqCheck.new
```

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
  MrWorker.perform_async('do_work', user.id)
rescue Redis::CannotConnectError => e
  MrWorker.new.perform('do_work', user.id)
end
```