# How to find Sidekiq is running or not

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

In one of my project i am using [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/)

Is there any inbuilt Sidekiq console method/method that helps me to find whether sidekiq is running or not.

My requirement is kind of a pre check condition where if Sidekiq is not running i will raise a error.

I tried using the grep like

```
'ps -ef | grep sidekiq'
```

but it's not solving my purpose.

The method i am looking for should be something  like:

```
Sidekiq.is_running?
```

Thanks in advance.

**I also Tried**

*Sidekiq not running*

```
1.9.3p392 :021 > system 'ps aux | grep sidekiq'
ankitgupta      6683   0.0  0.0  2432768    600 s001  R+   11:47AM   0:00.00 grep sidekiq
ankitgupta      6681   0.0  0.0  2433432    916 s001  S+   11:47AM   0:00.01 sh -c ps aux | grep sidekiq
 => true
```

*Sidekiq is running*

```
1.9.3p392 :022 > system 'ps aux | grep sidekiq'
ankitgupta      6725   0.0  0.0  2432768    600 s001  S+   11:57AM   0:00.00 grep sidekiq
ankitgupta      6723   0.0  0.0  2433432    916 s001  S+   11:57AM   0:00.00 sh -c ps aux | grep sidekiq
ankitgupta      6707   0.0  1.3  3207416 111608 s002  S+   11:56AM   0:07.46 sidekiq 2.11.2 project_name [0 of 25 busy]  
 => true
```

It is always returning true.. I want to catch the process when it runs

Comment: try 'ps aux | grep sidekiq'

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev , see my question.. i updated with what i tried (ur suggestion ).  It always gives me true

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843637/how-to-tell-if-sidekiq-is-connected-to-redis-server

Answer (score 43):

A little trick:

```
ps aux | grep '[s]idekiq'
```

Hope it works

Comment: Curious - why the `s` needs to be in `[]`?

Comment: good explanation here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/153419/how-does-this-tricky-bracket-expression-in-grep-work

Answer (score 8):

Ideally you can do this directly from ruby itself. Put this in some rake task or standalone script (don't forget to specify Sidekiq connection details)

```
ps = Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new
ps.size # => 2
ps.each do |process|
  p process['busy']     # => 3
  p process['hostname'] # => 'myhost.local'
  p process['pid']      # => 16131
end
ps.each(&:quiet!) # equivalent to the USR1 signal
ps.each(&:stop!) # equivalent to the TERM signal
```

From https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#processes

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375711/more-elegant-ps-aux-grep-v-grep) for how to filter ps output using grep, while eliminating the grep command from the the output.

Answer (score 1):

I see, try this out:

```
module Process
  class << self
    def is_running?(pid)
      begin
        Process.kill(0, pid)
        true
      rescue Errno::ESRCH
        false
      end
    end
  end
end

1.9.3p392 :001 > puts `ps aux | grep -i [s]idekiq`
```

It'll return you pid like: 12247, and you can check if it's running:

```
Process.is_running?(12247) // true | false
```

Comment: I wanted to check this on fly and didn't wanted to depend on PID so i created the method from your idea (Updated your Answer with what "I used" ) and returning matchdata.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines to your `config/routes.rb`

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
```

Start your server, open a browser and check your processess and your jobs

You can find it from [Sidekiq Wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki)